# dhcp status in linux

Tags: linux, dhcp

How to find in linux(fedora12) if dhcp is running on network?

Comment: Look at this [post](http://serverfault.com/questions/8526/how-do-i-find-if-there-is-a-rogue-dhcp-server-on-my-network). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Run a DHCP client.  I'm not familiar with Fedora, but one of `dhclient`, `pump` or `dhcpcd` should be installed.

Assuming you only have one network interface and it is wired (eth0) then one of the following should work:

```
dhclient -d eth0
pump -i eth0
dhcpcd -d -f eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a sniffer and look for DHCP traffic.

Comment: What's a sniffer? Which one? How to look for DHCP traffic?